# Drawing lines between nodes/points on ARCore flutter

Tags: android, flutter, arcore

I'm developing an AR related app using ArCore flutter, and I want to render a small circle on tap and draw a line between points. I don't find any documentation related to rendering of points or drawing a line using ARCore on flutter.

I followed the sample given from the [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/arcore_flutter_plugin) and I dont find any usefull information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.